# Bootstrap form in modal doesn't submit

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, pug, bootstrap-modal

When clicking 'submit', the form doesn't respond (and nothing is sent to server). I temporarily set the value of the form to GET from a random website. The close button correctly closes the modal. I worked off of [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/0fscmf3L/)

```
   html 
        body
            #editModal.modal.fade(tabindex="-1", role="dialog", aria-labelledby="myModalLabel", aria-hidden="true")
                .modal-dialog
                    .modal-content
                        // Modal Header
                        .modal-header
                            button.close(type="button", data-dismiss="modal")
                                span(aria-hidden="true") ×
                                span.sr-only Close
                            h4#myModalLabel.modal-title
                                | Edit Resource
                        // Modal Body
                        .modal-body
                            #editForm.form(role='form' method='GET' action='https://www.google.com/') // CHANGE THIS!
                                div.form-group
                                    label(for='name') Name:
                                    input#name.form-control(type='text', name='name', required='')
                                div.form-group
                                    label(for='address') Address:
                                    input#address.form-control(type='text', name='address')
                                div.form-group
                                    label(for='phone') Phone:
                                    input#phone.form-control(type='text', name='phone')
                                div.form-group
                                    label(for='website') Website:
                                    input#website.form-control(type='text' name='website')
                                div.form-group
                                    label(for='email') Email:
                                    input#email.form-control(type='email' name='email')
                                div.form-group
                                    label(for='description') Description:
                                    textarea#description.form-control(type='text', name='description', rows = '5')
                                button.btn.btn-primary(type="submit", name="asdf") Submit
                                button.btn.btn-default(type="button", data-dismiss="modal")
                                    | Close
```

Comment: Try:    form(method='GET' action='https://www.google.com/') , maybe revert  to POST again to test

Comment: No, clicking the button is still unresponsive :(

Comment: Changed from "#editForm.form" to only "form" and seems to have worked, take a look in this codepen: https://codepen.io/SitePoint/pen/eJXoQK   - submit button is taking some effect

Comment: You're right! Correct syntax is form#formId(role="form"). I ended up just writing a submit function to make the POST request. Thank you very much!

Comment: Great. I put this as answer to make more visible and eventually help others. If you can, please accept it for the same reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed from "#editForm.form" to only "form" and seems to have worked, take a look in this code, also in [codepen](https://codepen.io/dpetrini/pen/yPMeBg):

```
body
  p test
  .modal-dialog
    .modal-content
      // Modal Header
      .modal-header
        button.close(type="button", data-dismiss="modal")
          span(aria-hidden="true") ×
          span.sr-only Close
        h4#myModalLabel.modal-title
          | Edit Resource
      // Modal Body
      .modal-body
        //#editForm.form(role='form' method='GET' action='https://www.google.com/')
        form(role='form' method='GET' action='https://www.google.com/')
          div.form-group
            label(for='name') Name:
            input#name.form-control(type='text', placeholder='name' name='name')
          div.form-group
            label(for='email') Email:
            input#email.form-control(type='email', placeholder='name@email.com' name='email')
          button.btn.btn-primary(type="submit", name="asdf") Submit
          button.btn.btn-default(type="button", data-dismiss="modal")
            | Close
```